# node.js (or nwjs) ftp download

Tags: node.js, ftp

Need to download new files periodicaly from public ftp:
ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/bulletin/

But I cannot connect ftp module to sever. My code is:

```
var url = "ftp://ftp.cmegroup.com/bulletin/";
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
//var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Client = require('ftp');

var c = new Client();

var connectionProperties = {
    host: "ftp.cmegroup.com",
};

c.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('ready');
    c.list(function (err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;
        list.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
            //Ignore directories
            if (element.type === 'd') {
                console.log('ignoring directory ' + element.name);
                return;
            }
            //Ignore non zips
            if (path.extname(element.name) !== '.zip') {
                console.log('ignoring file ' + element.name);
                return;
            }
            //Download files
            c.get(element.name, function (err, stream) {
                if (err) throw err;
                stream.once('close', function () {
                    c.end();
                });
                stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(element.name));
            });
        });
    });
});


c.connect(connectionProperties);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21
```

Can't understand why it connects to localhost despite I pointed connection params.

Comment: Looks more like a problem with your DNS/Host file then the actual code. I tried it on my machine and it connects to the server fine

Comment: hmm.. but from browser connection is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lack of one line

```
c.connect(connectionProperties);
```